# Problem with sentence structures

Tags: grammar

I have problem with sentences structures.

I have sentences:

> I specialize in design wireless and wired network infrastructure,
>   configure devices company's Cisco Systems and MikroTik, and security
>   and techniques used successfully to protect IT resources.
>   Additionally, I have knowledge of voice over IP (VoIP) technology.

I am not sure, is this sentence grammatically correct?

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1):

The bit that goes "configure devices company's (stuff)" makes no sense to me. What is the relationship between "devices" and "company's"? It looks as if there are words missing, such as "configure devices, (comma) SUCH AS MY company's (stuff)". If not,  I cannot tell what you actually mean.

Answer (score 1):

Going for parallelism in ing-forms:

*I specialize **in designing** wireless and wired network infrastructure, **in configuring**  company's Cisco Systems and MikroTik **devices**, and **in implementing** security **measures designed to protect IT resources**. Additionally, **I am dabbling in** voice over IP (VoIP) technology.*

**I am dabbling in**: just a joke that occurred to me while looking for an idea on parallelism. Relax :-)

Alternately, going for parallelism in nouns:

*I specialize in wireless and wired network **infrastructure**, in  company-level Cisco Systems and MikroTik device **configuration**, and in security **measures** designed to protect IT resources.  Additionally, I have knowledge of voice over IP (VoIP) technology.*